# How to set a variable identifier as the contents of another variable?

Tags: python, batch-file, variables, cmd

I am trying to implement something in batch into Python as I am currently halfway through converting a batch game into syntax python can use.

```
FOO='YEET'
(FOO)='BAR'
print(YEET)
```

and then the desired output is

```
>>>BAR
```

If you know batch here is the equivalent code as it may help you answer better. This works and is what I am trying to convert into python.

```
SET FOO=YEET
SET %FOO%=BAR
ECHO %YEET%
```

and of course then output:

```
> BAR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foo = 'YEET'
vars = {} # a dict
vars[foo] = 'BAR'
print(vars['YEET'])
```

Comment: @SamuelPollard: Glad it helped.  You can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to SO.